# Python Matplotlib style file: show only horizontal gridlines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to define a matplotlib style file (.mplstyle) to only show horizontal gridlines. I know I can do it in python with

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
```

but I want to do it in the mplstyle file. The [classic.mplstyle](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/classic.mplstyle) file has the option `axes.grid.axis: both` set. I tried changing this to `axes.grid.axis: y`, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

Is it possible to do this in a style file?

EDIT:

An attempt at getting this to work:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
volume = [1, 2, 3, 4]
plt.style.use('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/luisdelatorre012/b36899e6dca07d05e73aca80eceb3098/raw/43ae73605b5e33dfc3f0d7e5d423ff997fc8325c/tiny.mplstyle')
d = pd.DataFrame({'Month': month, 'Volume': volume})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
b = d.plot(kind='bar', y="Volume", x="Month", ax=ax)
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()
```

The file tiny.mplstyle contains

```
axes.grid.axis: y
axes.grid: True
```

and nothing else.

This is the result:

[image: gridlines]

Comment: Did you restart Matplotlib?

Comment: @Joe, I'm testing this in a jupyter notebook and restart the kernel before I re-run, so that multiple matplotlib style files don't get applied together. Is that what you're referring to?

Answer (score 4):

You need to turn the grid on as well,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["axes.grid.axis"] ="y"
plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = True
```

or in the matplotlibrc file:

```
axes.grid.axis : y
axes.grid : True
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried two things so far, both of which result in both horizontal and vertical lines being shown.

1) changing axes.grid.axis to y and axes.grid to True in ggplot.mplstyle
2) using a .mplstyle file that contains only the lines axes.grid.axis: y and axes.grid: True.

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: matplotlib 2.0.2

Comment: Ok, what destroys the setting somehow is the use of pandas. I don't know the reason yet, but for a matplotlib plot alone it seems to work fine. Would you like to file a bug report at pandas, or do you want me to do it?

Comment: Thanks. I filed a bug report on pandas' github.

Comment: To make this useful for future readers you should link to issue.

Comment: Here is the issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17725#issuecomment-333246592